# ASP.net and anjularjs ng-route

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm using ASP.net MVC and AngularJS to create a Single Page Application (SPA).
I have a Main page with left menu panel. When click the menu link in the menu panel, it will show the content (view) in the right div. But the URL will change but i want keep the URL remain at the Main page URL.

Below is my code:
Main View

```
<a href="#/Admin">Member</a>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when("/Admin", {
        templateUrl: "/Admin/Member",
        controller:"AdminController"
    });
});
```

Admin is my controller (AdminController) and the Member is my content want to show.

Example URL Main: http://localhost:58741/Admin/Main
after click member link
Example URL Main: http://localhost:58741/Admin/Main#/Admin

Answer (score 0):

try using #stateProvider

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ui.router']);
app.config(
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Admin");

    $stateProvider
    .state('Admin', {
      url: "/Admin",
      templateUrl: "Admin.html"
    })
    .state('Admin.Member', {
      url: "/Member",
      templateUrl: "member.html"
    });

});
```

and in the HTML

```
<div  ng-controller="AdminController as ctrl">
  <a id="member" ui-sref=".Member"></a>
 <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```